# not able to import dataframe from pandas while using google colab

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-colaboratory

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import dataframe
import datetime
import pandas.io.data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

> ImportError: cannot import name 'dataframe'

Comment: Try this `from pandas import DataFrame`

Answer (score 1):

Try import dataframe using this:

```
import pandas as pd
data_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```